# Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

i configured accordingly. However i am getting error

logstash.yml

```
http.host: '0.0.0.0'
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.hosts: ["https://es1:9200","https://es2:9200","https://es3:9200"]
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.ssl.certificate_authority: '/usr/share/logstash/ca-ca.pem'
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username: 'elastic'
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password: 'myPassword'
```

logstash.conf

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    ssl => true
  }
}
```

```
 Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error {:url=>"https://127.0.0.1:9200/", :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :message=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [https://127.0.0.1:9200/][Man
```

Comment: can you please add here error stack trace as well

Comment: i have add the error. i want to send logs from logstash to elasticsearch. i bring up via docker-compose the infra

Comment: if i add cacert in logstash.conf, i am getting 401 error. is it needed to input password? why do we need password when we have cert

Comment: Is elasticsearch running in the same container as logstash? You didn't specify any hosts to the elasticsearch output in your logstash configuration, you need to tell logstash where are the hosts, otherwise it will try to talk to elasticsearch at localhost.

Answer (score 4):

### Only recommended for dev environments

**It can at least get you going in the right direction for a 'production' solution**

I had this same issue, I have a docker environment that I run all my logstash pipelines from. In production there is no issue but I started using a dockerized elastic cluster for my dev/test work.

I connect to that cluster from other applications I develop with no issue.

I tried doing what @OP outlined above and even took it a step further and disabled ssl verification at the output level:

```rb
# myPipeline.conf
output {
  elasticsearch {
    ssl => true
    ssl_certificate_verification => false
  }
}
```

But I was still getting the same errors about resurrecting connections and failing.

After looking through various docs and posts for and answer, [this one](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-unable-to-retrieve-license-information-from-license-server/264979/3) led me to a working solution.

Setting `xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.ssl.verification_mode` to `none` in the `logstash.yml` config file worked for me.

```yaml
# logstash.yml
http:
  host: "0.0.0.0"
xpack:
  monitoring:
    enabled: true
    elasticsearch:
      username: 'elastic'
      password: 'myPassword'
      hosts: ["https://es1:9200","https://es2:9200","https://es3:9200"]
      ssl:
        verification_mode: none
```

#### Notes:

- I haven't tested it in conjunction with the `xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.ssl.certificate_authority` setting.
- Disabling SSL verification can severely compromise security.
- If rolling out to a production site, test locally with this method to see if it is an issue with the signing of the SSL certificate as this will allow you to fine tune the solution to your specific problem.